# Difficulty with getting simple .bat to run

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-rename

I'm trying to get a simple `.bat` to run that renames files containing spaces to underscores instead. I created the `.bat` in notepad ++, and I'm running it on a networked drive. This is the command:

```bash
Q:\Planning dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ", "_"}

pause
```

I've tested this script in PowerShell inside this directory just like this and it works. I've also tested a `Robocopy` `.bat` I created in the same directory and it also works. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm not a programmer and have very very rudimentary programming skills.

Thanks for any help.

Tried testing out the command in PowerShell in the same directory, it works. Also tried a `robocopy` command and `.bat` containing same `robocopy` command in the same directory, also no issue. I'm assuming some form of user error on my part.

I just want to be able to run this `.bat` and rename files quickly to save a little bit of time, as it's something I do dozens of times per day. Should be straightforward to automate.

Comment: You can't run powershell commands directly in a batch file. Invoke them with the `powershell` command.

Comment: ```Q:\Planning dir``` is not a valid command in cmd.exe, powershell.exe, a batch file, (.cmd | .bat), or a PowerShell script, (.ps1).

Comment: In pure batch (without invoking powershell) you could utilize [String Substitution](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) to replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: From a batch file, preferably using the `.cmd` extension, not the 20th century `.bat` extension, it should look a little more like this: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Filter '* *' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace ' ', '_' }"```. Note how I'm using the full cmdlet name `Get-ChildItem`, not one of its aliases `gci`, `dir`, or `ls`.

Comment: Thanks all, Compo's suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but here is one example with pure batch:

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion     
    REM Change to the location you need.
    pushd "folder_location"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /A:-D ^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /C:" "') do (
    set "_fName=%%G"
    if defined _fName if not exist "!_fName: =_!" echo ren "%%G" "!_fName: =_!"
    )
```

You can remove the `echo` when you are done testing to execute the command.

EDIT: Modified with some of the helpful suggestions provided by @Magoo and @Compo.

Comment: Might be an idea to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` first...also to exclude directorynames from the `dir`.

Comment: Well I'd say, don't delay it until after `_fName` is defined, and end it after the rename. I'd also say that there's no need for the intermediate `set` command. As for the `dir` command, there is never a need to use `.`, and more of a need, for efficiency, to filter only files which have a space character in their basename, instead of renaming everything regardless.